# how to print all array value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have print all value in var $array1

```
<?php
    $array1 = array(10,11,12,13,14,"hello", array(1,2,3,4));
    print_r ($array1)
?>
```

output

> Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 11 [2] => 12 [3] => 13 [4] => 14 [5] => hello [6] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ) )

but I have print only array(1,2,3,4) value at a time.

Comment: print print_r ($array1[6]);

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to print the sub array in occurance `[6]` of `$array1`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `implode` array function.

**E.g.**

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
echo implode(", ",$arr);
```

**Result:**
1, 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
foreach ($array1 as $value){
   if (is_array($value)){ // Check the value is an array or not
        $subArr = $value;
   }
}

echo "Sub array value is :";
print_r($subArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try it get the count of the array and print the array in for loop   
  <?php
        $array1 = array(10,11,12,13,14,"hello");
        $count=count($array1);
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
        {
            echo $array1[$i];
            echo '<br/>';
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't know which is the array..

```
foreach ($array1 as $value)
   if (is_array($value))
      print_r($value);
```

Comment: sorry why the down vote? this is doing as requested but without having to specify the index where the array is